# How can I use the theorem : invariance of domain to prove that if $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is homeomorphic to $V \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ then $n = m$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I suppose $n < m$($m > n$ is same), and the map $f:U \to U'$ is the homeomorphism. We have $\mathbb{R}^n$ is closed in the $\mathbb{R}^m$ then $U$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^m$. Can we come to the contradiction that if $U'$ is open then $U$ is open too.

But the fact:if $U'$ is open then $U$ is open too only makes sense on the sphere?How can I improve my proof?

Comment: Even admitting that "$\Bbb R^n$ is closed in $\Bbb R^m$" (which should really be replaced with a more precise statement), why should an *open* subset of a closed subset be closed?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I am wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, there's a natural embedding $\mathbb{R}^n \subset \mathbb{R}^m$. Consider the inverse map $f^{-1}: V \to U$. It is also a homeomorphism, and so it's continuous and injective. Since $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. we can compose $f^{-1}$ with inclusion map $i: \mathbb{R}^n \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ to get a map $i \circ f^{-1}: V \to \mathbb{R}^m$ that is continuous and injective. Since $V \subset \mathbb{R}^m$, invariance of domain tells us that its image is open in $\mathbb{R}^m$. But its image is contained in $\mathbb{R}^n$, which has empty interior in $\mathbb{R}^m$, a contradiction.

Comment: But the edition I know is the situation on the sphere does there any differences?

Comment: What is on the sphere?

Comment: Inveriance of domain

Comment: What is the exact statement you have then?

Comment: If $f:U\to V$ is a homeomorphism, $U,V\subset S^n$ and if V is open in $S^n$ then $U$ is open in $S$

Comment: Try using your invariance of domain on spheres to prove the invariance of domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$. A useful thing to note is that there's a homeomorphism $\mathbb{S}^n - \{p\} \simeq \mathbb{R}^n$ -- this is stereographic projection.

Comment: Yes I wanted use the stereographic projection before, but how to do with that point is right ? If that we choose the point p that is not in the  $U$?